# I can´t print out 0 . Can someone tell me why?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, continue

I can´t print out 0 . Can someone tell me why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Number: ");
        int number = read.nextInt();
        //your code goes here
        while (number >= 0) {
            if(number % 3 == 0) {
                number--;
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(number);
            number--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change your loop to `number > 0`.

Comment: `0 % 3 == 0` is `true` and is consumed by `if`, therefore 0 cannot be printed

Comment: while (number >= 0) {
            if (number == 0) {
                
            } else if (number % 3 == 0) {
                number--;
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(number);
            number--;
        }

Comment: What's happening instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Answer (score 1):

You continue passed the `0` and never output it:

```
if(number % 3 == 0) {
   number--;
   continue;
}

0 % 3 == 0 // TRUE
```

You will need to have special handling for the `0` case with the logic you have currently. I will leave it for you to figure that part out.

Comment: Thank you! I did it and it works but is it right? Can i just leave  if-statement empty?

Comment: while (number >= 0) {
            if (number == 0) {
                
            } else if (number % 3 == 0) {
                number--;
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(number);
            number--;
        }